# preg_match regexp syntax extracting up to ;

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a file containing key/value pairs with on occasional comment (delimited by a ';') that a want to parse with preg_match (or maybe preg_match is the wrong tool).

The file looks like this

```
  key1 VALUE1
  key2 VALUE2 ; comment 2
  key3 VALUE3a VALUE3b
  key4 VALUE4a VALUE4b ; comment 4
```

(there is one or more whitespaces at the beginning of each line)

My preg_match looks like this
`preg_match('/\s*(\S+)\s+(.+)/', $line, $result);`
which correctly splits the lines "key1" and "key3". For key2 and key4 the "; comment #" becomes part $result[2].
Is it possible "remove" the ";comment" part directly in the preg_match (I do not care if the "; comment" part ends up in $result[3].

Comment: You may use a couple of `explode`s in your case. First, get the array of lines, then explode a trimmed string with `;` or `" ; "`, then get the first element and `explode` into 2 parts at the first space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it using this regex :

```
\s*(\S+)\s+([^;]+)
```

[see there](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/hMZ)

Answer (score 0):

You may use a couple of explodes in your case. First, get the array of lines, then explode a trimmed string with `;` or `" ; "`, then get the first element and explode into 2 parts at the first space.

```
$str = '  key1 VALUE1
  key2 VALUE2 ; comment 2
  key3 VALUE3a VALUE3b
  key4 VALUE4a VALUE4b ; comment 4';
$lines = explode("\n", $str);
$res = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $t = explode(" ; ", trim($line));
    $ch = explode(" ", $t[0], 2);
    $res[$ch[0]] =  $ch[1];
}
print_r($res);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/BWVyJ0)

If you prefer a regex, you may use

```
preg_match_all('~^\h*(\w+)\h+([^;\n]+)~m', $str, $res);
```

See [this PHP demo](https://ideone.com/BWVyJ0) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MrfXqw/1).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of line `^`
- `\h*` - zero or more horizontal whitespaces
- `(\w+)` - Group 1 capturing one or more word chars into Group 1 (you may use `\S+` if there can be non-word chars)
- `\h+`- one or more horizontal whitespaces
- `([^;\n]+)` -  Group 2 capturing any 1+ chars other than a newline and `;`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, basically you just need to preg match everything up to the first `;`.

Everything before the comma is what you want. If there is no comma at all you take the whole line.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
$txt = '
key1 VALUE1\n
key2 VALUE2 ; comment 2\n
key3 VALUE3a VALUE3b\n
key4 VALUE4a VALUE4b ; comment 4\n';

foreach(explode('\n', $txt) as $line){
    preg_match('/(.*);.*/', $line, $group);
    if(empty($group)){
        $result = $line;//no comma found so take whole line
    }else{
        $result = $group[1];//comma found so take first matching.
    }
    echo $result."\n<br />";
}
```

Will print:

```
key1 VALUE1
key2 VALUE2
key3 VALUE3a VALUE3b
key4 VALUE4a VALUE4b
```